# Send data from Share Extension to Xamatin.Forms app

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, share-extension

I work on Share Extension. And it only has a sample project (following link) and a general extension documentation.

[Basic project:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/ios-samples/ios8-share/)

[Extension documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/xamarin/ios/platform/extensions)

When I click share with my app on iphone (for example on photos), I want to send this file to my app and upload it remote server. But I couldn't find anyway to send object from share extension. I looked up and probably I need to use "NSUserDefaults" and I tried to use it that:

1. I did necessary settings (creating group id, app id etc) on my apple developer account.
2. I did necessary settings on my project Entitlements.plist
3. I try to send on ShareViewController - DidSelectPost method in the my project's share extension as below:

```
var default = new NSUserDefaults ("group.com.myapp.AppName", NSUserDefaultsType.SuiteName); 
default.SetString ("Test content", "TestKey"); 
default.Synchronize ();
```

4)I try to receive string data on my main project's AppDelegate as below:

```
var default = new NSUserDefaults ("group.com.myapp.AppName", NSUserDefaultsType.SuiteName);
var key = default.StringForKey ("TestKey");
string value = key;
```

But I couldn't do it. And I saw someone did this with OpenUrl function. I tried this and this didn't work.

I started mobile programming with Xamarin forms and I don't know enough native iOS programming (I only learn with Xamarin). I think share extension has insufficient documentation.

Comment: About sending data from share extension to app, I find one article that you can take a look:[iOS App Extensions: Data Sharing](https://dmtopolog.com/ios-app-extensions-data-sharing/), and I also search one sample that you can take a look:https://github.com/rolfbjarne/todaysharing/tree/master

Comment: I tried these. The steps I did in the apple section are correct. Because they are same with above github repo example. But while the ios app is in the background, I couldn't open the app from share extension. So I couldn't get data with NSUserDefaults. I looked up article. Probably it mention that this section: "5. NSURLSession cache". But I couldn't do this for xamarin ios.

Comment: NOTE: I want to open my xamarin app from share extension because I want to do these: to open the photos and to click "share with my application". After that I want to open my app and get this data (with NSUserDefaults or anythings) and upload file/files to the remote server.

Comment: Now you have solved your issue , anything update?

Comment: Yes I solved this issue. But I could do it in new solution. I can't implement it to my business project. NSUserDefaults comes null on my business project. Maybe cause is version difference. But I didn't find difference. So I put this task on hold for now. But example project on following link. Maybe it helps another one. https://github.com/Pelinalpp/XamarinShareExtension